# does django-nonrel is compatible with django 1.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-nonrel

I am using Django 1.7 and I want to use MongoDB, So for that I try to install django-nonrel. Please let me know django-nonrel is compatible with Django 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Django-nonrel isn't "compatible" with anything. It is actually a fork of Django, currently based on the 1.5 release.

Comment: Please let me know How I can use MongoDB in django1.7, As my project is already in 1.7.

Comment: django-nonrel is compatible with many things, its currently based on Django 1.6.5 and so far we haven't faced a problem with it and works like charm with other part of the django ecosystem.